# immer - Nested produce calls are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, immutability, immer.js

```
const { produce } = require("immer");

const outer = produce((draft) => {
  return inner(draft);
}, {});

const inner = produce((draft) => {
  draft.arr = [4, 5, 6];
}, {});

outer().arr.sort();
inner().arr.sort();
```

link: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wiles-ezqtr

There is an error on `inner().arr.sort()`. (read-only error)
My expectation is that `outer().arr.sort()` also be an error. 
Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `inner` doesn't have a return value, so it produces `undefined` implicitly.

Comment: Do you want use immer to sort an array, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want an nested produce but as my understanding you are trying to write a function that leverage immer to sort an array so, to avoid changing initial array.

This is how you could go and from here use another "produce" function that does that. ([Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-leftpad-39lm7?file=/src/nested.js:0-286))

```
const { produce } = require("immer")

const baseArray = [6, 10, 3, 2, 1]
const baseArray2 = [17, 9, 10, 3, 2, 1];

function sortedF(state) {
  return produce(state, (draft) => {
    const sorted = draft.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    console.log(sorted);
  });
}

const sorted1 = sortedF(baseArray)
console.log(sorted1); // [1, 2, 3, 6, 10]
```

This use a carried solution [curried-produce](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/curried-produce)

```
const sortedCarried = produce((draft) => {
  const sorted2 = draft.sort((a, b) => a - b)
});

const sorted2 = sortedCarried(baseArray2)
console.log(sorted2); // [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 17]
```